# Performance tuning for gap analysis of table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, gaps-and-islands

I have a table which stores the sequence (counter) of data received from devices out in the field.  At any rate, these sequences need to be in order within a configurable time span, but can come into the system out of order.  If a device is reset, then it's sequence number is set back to 0.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TapGapDetail]
(
[Id] [bigint] NOT NULL, --FK to another table
[DeviceESN] [varchar] (100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[TapDateUTC] [datetime] NOT NULL, --date event occurred on device
[CreatedDateUTC] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Counter] [int] NOT NULL,
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CX_TapGapDetail] ON [dbo].[TapGapDetail] ([DeviceESN], [CreatedDateUTC], [Counter]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I've tried to switch the order the CX by DeviceESN and CreatedDateUTC, but on my system it doesn't seem to make much of a difference in the IO.  There are millions of rows in this table.

Example insert would be:

```
INSERT INTO TapGapDetail (1, 'A', '1/1/2012 01:00AM', '1/1/2012 01:10AM', 5)
INSERT INTO TapGapDetail (2, 'A', '1/1/2012 12:05AM', '1/1/2012 01:15AM', 4) --out of order by insert date
INSERT INTO TapGapDetail (3, 'A', '1/2/2012 12:00AM', '1/2/2012 12:05AM', 6) --back in order
INSERT INTO TapGapDetail (4, 'A', '1/3/2012 01:00AM', '1/3/2012 01:05AM', 8) --missing 7
INSERT INTO TapGapDetail (5, 'A', '1/3/2012 06:00AM', '1/3/2012 06:05AM', 9) --in order outside 'tolerance'
INSERT INTO TapGapDetail (6, 'A', '1/10/2012 06:00AM', '1/10/2012 06:05AM', 0) --device reset
```

The report needs to report that a gap has occurred once for this data. There is also a detail, but one step at a time.  I want to get it to run in less than 10 seconds, but seems to take at least 1.25 minutes on my local.  I have stat IO if needed.  So, the proc I created to get the "gaps" is like so:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetValidatorTapGapSummary]
    @Validator varchar(100) = ''
    ,@FilterDateUtc datetime
    ,@ToleranceHours int
AS

--temp table
SELECT 
RowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DeviceESN, CreatedDateUTC, [Counter]),  
DeviceESN, 
TapDateUTC,
CreatedDateUTC,
[Counter]
INTO #taps
FROM TapGapDetail
WHERE CreatedDateUTC >= @FilterDateUtc
Order By 1

--cx
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CX1 ON #taps(RowID)

--results
select  
    t.DeviceESN as Validator
    ,sum(
        case 
            --They are in sequence
            when t2.[Counter] = t.[Counter]+ 1 then 0 
            --A reset has occured
            when t2.[Counter] < t.[Counter] then 0 
            --A gap exists. Find the difference
            else (t2.[Counter] - t.[Counter] - 1) 
        end) 
        as TapGaps
    ,case 
        --gets the last tap date per validator
        when MAX(t.TapDateUTC) > MAX(t2.TapDateUTC) THEN MAX(T.TapDateUTC) 
        ELSE MAX(t2.TapDateUTC) 
    END 
    AS MaxTapDate
    ,case 
        --gets the last tap date per validator
        when MAX(t.CreatedDateUTC) > MAX(t2.CreatedDateUTC) THEN MAX(T.CreatedDateUTC) 
        ELSE MAX(t2.CreatedDateUTC) 
    END 
    AS MaxCreatedDate
from #Taps t 
    inner join #Taps t2 on t.DeviceESN = t2.DeviceESN and t2.RowID = t.RowID + 1
where t2.[Counter] != t.[Counter] + 1
 and t2.[Counter] > t.[Counter]
 And t.CreatedDateUTC >= @FilterDateUtc
 And t2.CreatedDateUTC >= @FilterDateUtc
 And (t.DeviceESN = @Validator Or @Validator = '')
 And Not Exists --edge case for when there is a gap at the end, tried with left join and stats are the same, so this is easier to read I think.
        (Select Top 1 Null From TapGapDetail tgd Where tgd.DeviceEsn = t.DeviceESN And (t.Counter + 1) = tgd.Counter 
            And tgd.CreatedDateUTC >= DateAdd(day, -1 * @ToleranceHours, t.CreatedDateUTC)
            And tgd.CreatedDateUTC <= DateAdd(day, @ToleranceHours, t.CreatedDateUTC))
group by t.DeviceESN
Order By MaxCreatedDate Desc, t.DeviceEsn

GO
```

An example STATIO would be:

```
Table 'TapGapDetail'. Scan count 5, logical reads 24060, physical reads 400, read-ahead reads 4590, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(2763981 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Table '#taps_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000051'. Scan count 1, logical reads 18246, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 251, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(154 row(s) affected)
Table '#taps_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000051'. Scan count 10, logical reads 37834, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 1240, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'TapGapDetail'. Scan count 5, logical reads 13563, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 13445, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

I've tried various indexes and what not on the temp table, but I suspect that even just filling is taking too long.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Thanks to the CTE, it runs in 14 seconds with a few more indexes added.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a different method.

For a start, don't populate a temporary table with 2.7M rows - that's not going to want to return in under ten seconds. You could use a CTE instead, and that might work much better.

```
WITH taps as (
SELECT 
RowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DeviceESN, CreatedDateUTC, [Counter]),  
DeviceESN, 
TapDateUTC,
CreatedDateUTC,
[Counter]
FROM TapGapDetail
WHERE CreatedDateUTC >= @FilterDateUtc
)

--results
select  
    t.DeviceESN as Validator
    ,sum(
        case 
            --They are in sequence
            when t2.[Counter] = t.[Counter]+ 1 then 0 
            --A reset has occured
            when t2.[Counter] < t.[Counter] then 0 
            --A gap exists. Find the difference
            else (t2.[Counter] - t.[Counter] - 1) 
        end) 
        as TapGaps
    ,case 
        --gets the last tap date per validator
        when MAX(t.TapDateUTC) > MAX(t2.TapDateUTC) THEN MAX(T.TapDateUTC) 
        ELSE MAX(t2.TapDateUTC) 
    END 
    AS MaxTapDate
    ,case 
        --gets the last tap date per validator
        when MAX(t.CreatedDateUTC) > MAX(t2.CreatedDateUTC) THEN MAX(T.CreatedDateUTC) 
        ELSE MAX(t2.CreatedDateUTC) 
    END 
    AS MaxCreatedDate
from taps t 
    inner join taps t2 on t.DeviceESN = t2.DeviceESN and t2.RowID = t.RowID + 1
where t2.[Counter] != t.[Counter] + 1
 and t2.[Counter] > t.[Counter]
 And t.CreatedDateUTC >= @FilterDateUtc
 And t2.CreatedDateUTC >= @FilterDateUtc
 And (t.DeviceESN = @Validator Or @Validator = '')
 And Not Exists --edge case for when there is a gap at the end, tried with left join and stats are the same, so this is easier to read I think.
        (Select Top 1 Null From TapGapDetail tgd Where tgd.DeviceEsn = t.DeviceESN And (t.Counter + 1) = tgd.Counter 
            And tgd.CreatedDateUTC >= DateAdd(day, -1 * @ToleranceHours, t.CreatedDateUTC)
            And tgd.CreatedDateUTC <= DateAdd(day, @ToleranceHours, t.CreatedDateUTC))
group by t.DeviceESN
Order By MaxCreatedDate Desc, t.DeviceEsn
```

I'm not saying this is necessarily terrific (the "NOT EXISTS" bit could be a pain), but it's almost certainly an improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Rob.  I think I tried using CTE before, but figured I would need to index the temp results to get the perf I wanted.  Maybe I can try to fiddle with this and the indexes on the source table.  Here is the statio for just with CTE alone:

Comment: (154 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2763996, logical reads 16693695, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'TapGapDetail'. Scan count 3, logical reads 61093, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 1512, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: Ok. A few changes to make...

Comment: Don't join on DeviceESN, only RowID. Oh, plus a few other things... that filter on CreatedDateUTC, for example - is that particularly selective? If it is, your indexing strategy should be reconsidered.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by particularly selective.  It is fairly unique to the DeviceESN, but not guaranteed.  Sometimes the devices have some strange things going on with the dates. Also, I think after looking at the execution plan, maybe indexed persisted columns for the minus one and plus one would help.  I will take a look at joining by rowid.  Also added this to the CTE: And (@Validator = '' Or @Validator = DeviceESN)
And changed the other filter to be gated by the default first.

Comment: I changed it around to have a CX only on the Id (with you and Edward's help) column and selected the min/max id's at first since the created date should be in the same order as the id's. It now returns at 58 seconds on my local, which is a big improvement on the CTE.

Comment: I was meaning the `WHERE CreatedDateUTC >= @FilterDateUtc` filter. Does this filter the data to a small amount only, or is it still millions of rows that are having to be handled?

Comment: It filters it to a small amount for some of the time, but it can be set to up to 1 year, which will filter it down to about 2M records.

Comment: Marking this as the answer.  I still have a little ways to go, but the CTE is the right path.  Thanks for the help, Edward and Rob.

Answer (score 4):

If you create a clustered index on `createdDateUTC` the query Rob has given could be really fast.  Can you try that?

The other option would be to add an artificial unique `tapDetailID` column with a clustered index and use that instead.

Comment: Ok.  I think I understand.  I did switch the CreateDateUTC on the clustered to be first, but you are saying create it only on this, but it must be unique.  Hmmmm.  Maybe I should make a cluster on the existing ID column since it's unique and should be relatively ordered on insert?

Comment: No, I'm saying either create a clustered index on createdDateUtc or, add a artificial primairy key (auto identity) to the tapdetails table and create a clustered index on that, and then use that column instead of the rowid..

Comment: Hold on... From your first post I understood that the existing ID column was a Foreign key that referenced a primary key in a parent table. So I assumed (yeah never assume) this would be non unique anyway. But are you now saying that this is a unique primary key?

Comment: try creating the clustered index on the createdDateUTC first and see if Rob's, CTE is running faster with that.

Comment: Sorry, Edward.  Should have been more clear.  It's a "foreign key" which is copied from the pk of the parent table.  This table is built on changes to the primary table just to make this report more speedy.